# What is wrong in this syntax for MySQL 8 ? , it was working fine for 5.7

Tags: mysql

I'm installing Old vBulletin version 3.x which is running this query,

```
CREATE TABLE usertextfield (
    userid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    subfolders MEDIUMTEXT,
    pmfolders MEDIUMTEXT,
    buddylist MEDIUMTEXT,
    ignorelist MEDIUMTEXT,
    signature MEDIUMTEXT,
    searchprefs MEDIUMTEXT,
    rank MEDIUMTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
```

This always worked fine for older MySQL versions but giving syntax error with MySQL 8 .. 
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
'rank MEDIUMTEXT,
        PRIMARY (userid)
    )'
```

at line 9
while this almost identical Query executed fine and created the table.

```
CREATE TABLE administrator (
    userid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    adminpermissions INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    navprefs MEDIUMTEXT,
    cssprefs VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    notes MEDIUMTEXT,
    dismissednews TEXT,
    languageid SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
)
```

Could you please let me know what changed and what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANK` became a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL 8.0.2. You should rename the column, or surround it with ` marks, i.e.

```
`rank` MEDIUMTEXT,
```